# Please, how to convert decimal to binary to hex to octal without using toString() or any other pre-made method?

Tags: javascript

let num = 100;

    document.write("Num: " + num + "
");
    document.write("Binary: " + num.toString(2) + "
");
    document.write("8: " + num.toString(8) + "
");
    document.write("16: " + num.toString(16));

//I want this, but without toString() or any other method.

Comment: If you don't want to use a pre-made method, then you'll have to implement the logic yourself. Have you made any such attempt to implement the logic? Please post what you've tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow! This sounds like a homework question, because you have been asked to implement something that would normally be done using builtin methods. Here is the outline of how I would approach this, to help you get started.

If you had to write the number 100 in base 16, what would the last digit of the answer be?

How did you come to that conclusion?

Now what would the decimal value of the remainder of the hexadecimal number have to be? Hint: answer = 96.

How did you come to that conclusion?

Your last answer will be a multiple of 16, because you have removed already the remainder after dividing by 16. You have done: `number - (number modulo 16)`.

If you divide this by 16, you have a new, smaller number, which again you can convert into hexadecimal in the same way as above. In this manner you can keep extracting one hexadecimal digit at a time, until there is no reminder.

This gives your hexadecimal number, outputted in reverse order.

You can do the same for any base.

Comment: Yes it is homework :D Thanks for your help!